# Does use-package keep packages automatically updated?

Tags: use-package

I'm using use-package in my init.el for all my package installations and configuration. I thought specifying `:ensure t` in use-package would make sure I always have the latest versions installed. But when I did `M-x package-list-packages` the minibuffer tells me I have a number of package updates waiting. Isn't it enough to specify `:ensure t` in use-package, do I have to manually check for and install updates using `M-x package-list-packages`? What is the best way to handle updates when using use-package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:ensure` option in `use-package` does not automatically keep packages up to date. It ensures that the package is installed. This might be useful if you pull your Emacs config on to a new machine (or are using it across several machines), because when you start up all your required packages would get installed.

You'll still need to deal with installing updates.

Comment: The reason I've heard as to _why_ that's the case is because updating packages can break them, so it would regress in functionality.

Comment: @zck I think it's more that `use-package` is meant to provide a quick startup and checking for updates would be slow. Also, [the author of `use-package` doesn't use package.el packages](https://github.com/jwiegley/dot-emacs/blob/master/init.el), any related features (like `:ensure`) were tacked on afterwards by other users. In the original design, all packages are considered optional, your init.el just skips configuration of missing packages.

Answer (score 14):

I use `auto-package-update` to automatically update packages.

```el
(use-package auto-package-update
   :ensure t
   :config
   (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t
         auto-package-update-interval 4)
   (auto-package-update-maybe))
```

With that setup, packages will be updated every `4` days, and the old packages will be removed.

Comment: You might want to add this as an answer here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-to-update-packages-installed-with-use-package

Comment: It appears to me that the call to ` (auto-package-update-maybe)` is not the value of one of use-package's keyword options.  Should it perhaps be wrapped in a progn as part of the :config, like this:
```
(use-package auto-package-update
   :ensure t
   :config (progn
   (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t
         auto-package-update-interval 4)
   (auto-package-update-maybe)))
```

Comment: should I do `(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))` before running this?