# Do MELPA packages get updated automatically?

Tags: package-repositories

The [website](https://melpa.org/#/) says they do:

> Automatic updates - new commits result in new packages

But I ask because if I go `M-x list-packages` and hit `U` there are many upgrades available for packages under the "melpa" archive.

Answer (score 3):

It means that MELPA packages are up-to-date towards upstream Git repositories. You still have to upgrade them yourself or using a package like `auto-package-update`.

See also "[Does use-package keep packages automatically updated?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31826/does-use-package-keep-packages-automatically-updated)".